# Perl: Remove non-letter, non-number characters from string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl string that is only allowed to contain the letters A to Z (capital and lowercase), the numbers 0 to 9, and the "-" and "_" characters. I want to remove all non-matching characters from the string, leaving the rest untouched.

So "Hell@_World" would become "Hell_World".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a substitution with the `^` (not) regular expression.  While Perl offers shortcuts, you can see the parts more clearly like this:

```
$string =~ s/[^[:alnum:]_-]//g;
```

where the `[:alnum:]` is the character class for alphabetic and numeric characters.  The "`-`" is last in the brackets to avoid confusing it as part of a *range* of characters.

Comment: No problem.  (\w is more concise, but harder to remember offhand *what* it includes).

Comment: Can you provide a reference for `:alnum:`? It is not on [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: OK, it is in *[perlrecharclass - Perl Regular Expression Character Classes, POSIX Character Classes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes)*.

Comment: [`man perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) states that the longer (tutorial) is [`perlretut`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), and it's listed there.  I usually start with the manpages...